# Word web addin Ribbon Icons are not loaded when using desktop client

Tags: office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

[image]

we have given icons in all required sizes(16,32,64 )and even the urls are correct but still when the addin is not loaded all the icons are shown with default image as in the image
Which is loading perfectly in office 365 word.
Manifest file

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.setting">
              <Label resid="Contoso.setting.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="Contoso.setting.Label" />
                <Description resid="Contoso.setting.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="64" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon64" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.setting.Icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>Button2Id1</TaskpaneId>
                <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
                <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane5.Url" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
```

Comment: <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://192.168.1.101:8078/Images/logopng.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Check.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://192.168.1.101:8078/Images/check-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Check.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://192.168.1.101:8078/Images/check-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Check.Icon64" DefaultValue="https://192.168.1.101:8078/Images/check-64.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Check.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://192.168.1.101:8078/Images/check-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
  </Resources>

Comment: I wonder if the icons have to be served off of HTTPS rather than HTTP.  Have you tried that?

Comment: the icons are served off the HTTPS, the icons are fine in word online (365), so that is not the issue. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I am not sure.  I suggest you file a bug on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, maybe sharing your manifest and any other instructions as well.  BTW, if you publish to a regular website, does it work there (i.e., is it purely a 192.168.1.101 sort of issue?...)

Comment: @VishnuKayVee did you got the Icon working ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a long time since this issue was raised, but I ran into the exact same thing today with my add-in for Excel.  The icons displayed just fine when they were on in the web client, but when I ran from the desktop client, they were that same default icon that you were getting.

Ultimately, I found out that the problem was with the response headers that were included with my images.  My images were coming back with a "Cache-Control: no-store" header which we are told we should not do in the [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1).  Looking down to the "Hosting requirements" section it tells you that you should not return no-cache or no-store.  When I changed my headers to return "public" instead, the images showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to self signed certificate that you are using when you are doing local development if you publish your project to the server with valid certificate and if those resources are public you will see the icons. I saw similar behaviour when developing on Windows environment while on Mac I haven't had any issues. You might try to insert that self signed certificate as trusted to IE and see if it helps something I tried but it didn't worked for me.